# show dashboard related to user on vfpage

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

Is it possible to display the reports and dashboards in the visual force page? If yes, can anybody provide me with some reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

This is the easiest way probably.

[analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm?search_text=analytic)

You can specify the report ID and it pretty much takes care of the rest. It also comes with a refresh button.

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00O90000009VK2d"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

To fetch the private reports shown on the private dashboard, you need to do a few query.

1. Get the Dashboard ID using UserInfo.getUserId()

   `SELECT Id FROM Dashboard where FolderId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1`
2. Once you have the dashboardId, fetch its report components using another query:

   `SELECT CustomReportId,DashboardId FROM DashboardComponent where DashboardId = :dashboardId`

OR

You could fire both the query in a single SOQL:

```
SELECT CustomReportId,DashboardId FROM DashboardComponent where DashboardId IN (select ID  FROM Dashboard where FolderId = :UserInfo.getUserId())
```

So all the `CustomReportId` returned in the last query will be your list of report IDs to be passed on to `analytics:reportChart`.

Comment: reportId is hardcoded. i need whichever user logged in get their personal dashboard how we can get from userinfo.getuserId();

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question itself. Anyway, updated my answer.

Comment: Did it helped you? if yes, please close the thread by accepting the answer, if not, let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in that way:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_basic_dashboard_components.htm